# Dashboard with 5 sortable responsive grids in foundation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, jquery-ui-sortable

[image][image]

I am trying to create a dashboard with 5 sortable responsive grids in foundation. Four grids have same widths and one has double the width of the other grids. The grids have to be responsive and mobile friendly. They have to stack under one another for resolutions <= 768. I tried using many libraries. For some I had containment issues and for some padding/gutter issues and responsive issues.

The below code is my latest trial. It has intermittent containment issues when we sort along y axis and breaks when gutter between grids is introduced.
I am new to foundation, sorting. Please check the below code and let me know how to fix the above two issues.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/3.2.2/stylesheets/foundation.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .list {
            background-color: pink;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .listDbl {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background-color: pink;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sortable">
        <div class="row display">
            <div class="ui-state-default large-4 columns list">1</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default large-4 columns list">2</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default large-4 columns list">3</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default large-8 columns listDbl">4</div>
            <div class="ui-state-default large-4 columns list">5</div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/3.2.2/javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
            $(function() {
                $(".row").sortable();
                $(".row").disableSelection();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBSA4/66/

Comment: add this on fiddle or something

Comment: @nolawipetros This is the code in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBSA4/66/   I am not sure we can test this in the jsfiddle since we are using foundation and it has to be responsive. So I didn't include the fiddle earlier.

Comment: am sorry the question is not clear? I thought i would understand if fiddle but i am not understanding. any mockups

Comment: @nolawipetros There have to be 5 grids in two  rows. The first row has three grids (33.3333% each). the second row has two grids (one 33.33% and the other 66.666%). These grids have to be sortable within the container. The grids change to 100% and stack (one grid per row) for 768 and under resolutions. I don't have the mocks.

Comment: @nolawipetros I have added the snaps of how it looks.

Comment: ok thanks .. working on an answer

Answer (score 0):

OK it works here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/uq8puqy2/

you were using foundation 3.2

```
   http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/3.2.2/stylesheets/foundation.min.css
```

use 5 or better version because the column markup has changed

Comment: It doesn't work. I added the latest version when I was working. Only in the fiddle, it had an old version. If you check the fiddle you provided, the two issues I mentioned in the original question are still present. It has intermittent containment issues when we sort along y axis and breaks when gutter between grids is introduced.